# How do I remove an account association?

Tags: support, user-accounts

My account is associated to a Stack Exchange site I don't want to be associated with (physics). How can I remove it? And remove my commit?

Comment: How would you tell the difference between 'no association' and 'forget it exists'?

Comment: @glowcoder, thanks for the help but I want to remove the association if possible.

Comment: I also want to undo my commitment to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can clear all associations via the button on your user page under the accounts tab.

If you do not wish an account associated, you *must* use a totally unique set of credentials on that site, with no emails or openids in common with any other site on our network.

Comment: I only want to clear one association. Removing my account from that one site..

Comment: @quanta it's only possible using the method I describe. It is highly unusual to be disconnected in the network, we optimize for being connected.

Comment: yeah I joined the particular site by accident and just want to undo it though. I don't want to clear all connections because it's good to have the others associated.

Comment: @Jeff I'm unable to find any such button _under the accounts tab_. Can you please tell where exactly do I find it.

Comment: @atul this was removed because it is no longer possible.

Comment: @Jeff is there any way to add this back?  I've got a site that I really want to remove the association for so it'll stop showing up at the top when I use the StackExchange navigation (alternately would there be a way to let us reset points for a specific site to 0? )

Comment: @eternal email the address at the bottom of every page

Comment: @jeff thanks Jeff, that worked :)