# Option to hide the Network Profile

Tags: feature-request

I know there's the option of disassociating all accounts from each other.

[The Stack Exchange Network Profile/Accounts links should be made optional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85977/the-stack-exchange-network-profile-accounts-links-should-be-made-optional)

But the problem there then is that well, your accounts are disassociated and you can't keep track of questions via one central place (the inbox).

For most users, who may be on 10 - 20 SE sites, they're not going to want to check each site to see how their questions or answers are going.

Why don't we just offer a way to hide your Network Profile if you want to?

Comment: From whom would you like to hide it? Yourself? The bogeyman?

Comment: @Cody : Please see the linked question for reasons why you may want to hide your network profile

Comment: I did...all I found was [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85977/the-stack-exchange-network-profile-accounts-links-should-be-made-optional/85985#85985), which seems to suggest there's no reason for this `feature-request`.

Comment: @Cody : that's the whole point of this question. Yes, you can post anonymously, but then they wouldn't be linked, you would lose all the benefits of having a linked account. You would have to keep track of all the questions you've participated, in all the sites. Given that you can troll the site by posting anonymously if you really wanted, why not just allow the network profile to be hidden?