# Is there a way to disable the public linking of accounts on various Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, support, profile-page, privacy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Stack Exchange Network Profile/Accounts links should be made optional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85977/the-stack-exchange-network-profile-accounts-links-should-be-made-optional)

I realized that anybody can see the list of Stack Exchange sites I currently use, read the questions I've asked, etc. I don't want people on A.stackexchange.com to see that I am a member of B.stackexchange.com, and/or that I've asked this stupid question there, etc. Is there a way to avoid this? I didn't see a relevant profile setting, am I missing something?

This is a somewhat major issue for me, I  will open different accounts for different sites if there is no way to get around this, but I think this really shouldn't be needed. I don't think this privacy decision should be made on our behalf by the StackExchange network.

Comment: In [December 2010](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72069/the-clear-all-associations-button-isnt-effective-with-aggressive-re-association/72075#72075): *you'll have to create a new OpenID for every site you visit, and make sure they have no email string in common.* Maybe things have changed though...

Comment: You might want to vote for [The Stack Exchange Network Profile/Accounts links should be made optional](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85977/the-stack-exchange-network-profile-accounts-links-should-be-made-optional).

Answer (score 0):

You CAN login with an unknown OpenID with unknown email to specific site , therefore it won't be associated with your other accounts.